# Magento 2 move header.links without mobile menu

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to move the `header.links` from `header.panel` to `header-wrapper` without removing the `header.links` from the mobile menu (store.links).

I tried it with a `referenceContainer` and the move command in `theme/Magento_Customer/layout/default.xml`

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

OR

```
<move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper"/>
```

Can someone tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom block to reference-container header-wrapper and add/copy the children from header.links to your new header.links.custom block.

new header.link.custom block:

```
 <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">           
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links.custom" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
 </referenceContainer>
```

copy/insert children (give them unique names, just added "-custom" here)

```
  <referenceBlock name="header.links.custom">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer-custom" template="Magento_Customer::account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login-custom" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
  </referenceBlock>
```

That should do the trick, maybe you have to hide the header.links.custom block with css in your mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

You can move header links using below code in  `theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
<move element="header.panel" destination="header-wrapper" after="-"/>
```